# Unable to stop LocationListener service

Tags: android, service, locationlistener

In a `Splash Activity`'s `onResume()`, I start the service this way

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.cancel(pi);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        ystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 20000, 60000, pi);
```

and in `onStop()`, I stop the service this way

```
stopService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
```

and the **Service Class** is:

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager mgr;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //get Location details
        mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                10 * 60 * 1000, 50, this);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    private void dumpLocation(Location l) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        mgr.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

Once I stop the service in `Splash Activity`'s `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` of the `LocationService` is triggered(which means the service is stopped?), but still after a minute as specified in the `AlarmManager` the service runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the pending intent for the alarm in a variable.  Call cancel on it when the service ends.

Comment: Remove `am.cancel(pi);` from `onResume()` and use it in `onStop()` before stopping the service?

Comment: No, since your activity owns the alarm it should be stopping it.  But if you want the alarms to stop when the service stops, you should cancel the intent when the service is stopped-  make the two calls one after the other.  Keep the cancel in onStop as well if you don't want the alarms to go off when you aren't foreground.